# Smoothing between two numbers which are continuously changing

Tags: c#

I am receiving values that are constantly changing. Let's say I receive 1 then 6 then 9 then 3 then 10 and so on. This makes my graphics on control jumping all around. I would like to smoothen this transition. After some research I have found an example, but it seems to be for Unity and for example Mathf class is not available outside Unity.

This:

```
private IEnumerator ChangeSpeed(float v_start, float v_end, float duration)
{
  float speed = 0.0f;
  float elapsed = 0.0f;
  while (elapsed < duration)
  {
    speed = Mathf.Lerp(v_start, v_end, elapsed / duration);
    elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    yield return null;
  }
  speed = v_end;
}
```

I have been trying to work it out by somehow dividing values into smaller ones to get change in decimals. So if I would get 1 and 6, I would remember these two values and then input into my property 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and so on until 6. This would decrease the step. However I am having hard times to understand how it can be done in principle.

What I have tried so far, not working, no smoothing:

```
private void StartRandomizer()
{
  // Create a timer with a two second interval.
  Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
  // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
  timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
  timer.AutoReset = true;
  timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  double oldValue = 0;
  Random random = new Random();
  double number = random.Next(1, 20) * 5;

  this.SmoothValue(number, oldValue);
  //ExpFilter expFilter = new ExpFilter(number, 1, 0.1);
  this.Speed = number;

  oldValue = number;
}

private double SmoothValue(double newValue, double oldValue)
{
  double difference = Math.Abs(newValue - oldValue) / 100;
  return difference;
}
```

Property Speed is double. Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example list of input numbers and the resulting list of "output" numbers you want to generate based on the given example input list.

Comment: Where do you want the intermediate values being saved? In which interval are the input values generated? How many intermediate values do you want to calculate? Does the number of intermediate values depends on the input numbers and/or depends on some time interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper method which returns the intermediate values for two given values and a given step size. The method can look like this:

```
public static IList<double> BuildIntermediateValues(double start, double end, double stepSize)
{
    if (stepSize <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The step size must be positive", nameof(stepSize));
    }
    IList<double> result = new List<double>();
    if (Math.Abs(start-end) < double.Epsilon) 
    {
        return result;
    }
    if (start < end)
    {
        // go up
        for (double d = start+stepSize; d<end; d+= stepSize)
        {
            result.Add(d);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // go down.
        for (double d = start-stepSize; d>end; d-= stepSize)
        {
            result.Add(d);
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

You can use it to get the intermediate values between two input values. The usage can look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<double> inputs = new double[] {1, 6, 9, 3, 10};
    for (int i=0; i<inputs.Count-1; i++)
    {
        double inputValue = inputs[i];
        double nextInputValue = inputs[i+1];
        Console.WriteLine($"Input value is: {inputValue}");
        IList<double> intermediateValues = BuildIntermediateValues(inputValue, nextInputValue, 1.25);
        foreach(double intermediate in intermediateValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Intermediate: {intermediate}");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Last input: {inputs.Last()}");
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Input value is: 1
Intermediate: 2.25
Intermediate: 3.5
Intermediate: 4.75
Input value is: 6
Intermediate: 7.25
Intermediate: 8.5
Input value is: 9
Intermediate: 7.75
Intermediate: 6.5
Intermediate: 5.25
Intermediate: 4
Input value is: 3
Intermediate: 4.25
Intermediate: 5.5
Intermediate: 6.75
Intermediate: 8
Intermediate: 9.25
Last input: 10
```

Adjust the `stepSize` values for your needs.